# Saving and resetting order in sortablejs

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I am using sortablejs to make a drag+drop list. I want two buttons, one that outputs the *current order of list elements*, and another that just *resets the current order back to its original state*.

I found a couple resources about how to [print the current order](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#toarraystring) and to how [reset it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846662/how-do-you-perform-a-reset-on-a-jquery-sortable), but since I'm still somewhat new to javascript, I've been having trouble implementing them.

Currently, my alert just outputs `[object HTMLUListElement]` and I can't figure out the reset.

Code below. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
//Initiate sortable list
Sortable.create(simpleList, {
  animation: 150});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Simple List -->
<ul id="simpleList" class="list-group">
  <li data-id="i1" class="col-1">#1</li>
  <li data-id="i2" class="col-2">#2</li>
  <li data-id="i3" class="col-3">#3</li>
  <li data-id="i4" class="col-4">#4</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" onclick="alert($('#simpleList').toArray())">Current order!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="">Reset!</button>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$('#simpleList').toArray()
```

The method **.toArray()** needs to be applied to the sortable instance.

```js
var simpleList = document.getElementById('simpleList');

// create sortable and save instance
var sortable = Sortable.create(simpleList, {animation: 150});

// save initial order
var initialOrder = sortable.toArray();

document.getElementById('saveCurrOrder').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    // print current order
    var order = sortable.toArray();
    console.log(order);
});

document.getElementById('resetOrder').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // reset to initial order
    sortable.sort(initialOrder);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>


<ul id="simpleList" class="list-group">
    <li data-id="i1" class="col-1">#1</li>
    <li data-id="i2" class="col-2">#2</li>
    <li data-id="i3" class="col-3">#3</li>
    <li data-id="i4" class="col-4">#4</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="saveCurrOrder">Current order!</button>
<button type="button" id="resetOrder">Reset!</button>
```